# ActiveRecord: how to select helper method result as a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

When using active record, I can select fields like this:

```
Model.select(:a_col,:b_col)
```

If the model has some helper methods defined, then I am doing this(which feels lame):

```
Model.all.map{|m|{a:m.a_col,b:m.b_col,c:m.someMethodCall()}}
```

Is there a way to do it like this?

```
Model.select(:a_col,:b_col,:someMethodCall)
```

Comment: I don't think so - for `select` you are specifying columns to be fetched from database, but - if I understand correctly what you mean by "helper methods" - they are a methods defined within model. This means they are on different level. There is no other way for combining them in `select`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `select` translates the symbol into the corresponding SQL database column

```
Model.select(:foo)
```

becomes

```
SELECT foo FROM models
```

as opposite to

```
SELECT * FROM models
```

Your database has no knowledge of the methods defined in your Ruby class. Therefore, what you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: in that case, is selecting and then mapping the instances into hashes the best way to do that?

Comment: You can mix both. You can select only the fields you need from the instance, and merge the attributes with the result of the method calls.